# Some kind of tabs just keep flashing

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to work with blender in "blender game". While being in game mode some kind of tabs just keep flashing. Constantly switching between game mode and these tabs in picture. How to solve this?[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical problem of some certain intel GPU's.

You could try to upgrade your drivers, or use a different render mode (GSL, Multitexture).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when I accidentally tried to run in "Multi-Texture" mode. Changing the display mode to GLSL always solved it for me.